# gensim - fasttext - Why `load_facebook_vectors` doesn't work?

Tags: python, gensim, fasttext

I've tried to load pre-trained FastText vectors from [fastext - wiki word vectors](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/pretrained-vectors.html).

My code is below, and it works well.

```py
from gensim.models import FastText
model = FastText.load_fasttext_format('./wiki.en/wiki.en.bin')
```

but, the warning message is a little annoying.

```
gensim_fasttext_pretrained_vector.py:13: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated `load_fasttext_format` (use load_facebook_vectors (to use pretrained embeddings)
```

The message said, `load_fasttext_format` will be deprecated so, it will be better to use `load_facebook_vectors`.

So I decided to changed the code. and My changed code is like below.

```py
from gensim.models import FastText
model = FastText.load_facebook_vectors('./wiki.en/wiki.en.bin')
```

**But**, the error occurred, the error message is like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gensim_fasttext_pretrained_vector.py", line 13, in <module>
    model = FastText.load_facebook_vectors('./wiki.en/wiki.en.bin')
AttributeError: type object 'FastText' has no attribute 'load_facebook_vectors'
```

I couldn't understand why these thing happen.
I just change what the messages said, but it doesn't work. 
If you know anything about this, please let me know.

Always, thanks for you guys help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there, you need to change two things:

- First of all, it's `fasttext` all lowercase letters, not `Fasttext`.
- Second of all, to use `load_facebook_vectors`, you need first to create a `datapath` object before using it.

So, you should do like so:

```
from gensim.models import fasttext
from gensim.test.utils import datapath

wv = fasttext.load_facebook_vectors(datapath("./wiki.en/wiki.en.bin"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. As you said, it works after chaging code like you said.

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: I'm glad it's working; note however you don't need to use `datapath`. The `load_facebook_vectors()` method on the module `gensim.models.fasttext` will take a plain string as long as it's to a valid file.

Comment: if you use `datapath`, the utility function will look for the file in the `/gensim/test/test_data/` dir, so if you downloaded a fasttext file in a dir of your own choice it will not be found.